# What are the applications of tetraxenonogold(II)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I recently stumbled upon a pretty interesting chemical: tetraxenonogold(II) $\ce{AuXe4^2+}.$ Basically, an atom of gold with four xenons around. It is a product of a superacid reaction and it is interesting because both gold and xenon are quite inert elements.

What could be the application of such a molecule? It reminds me of some cancerostatic compounds.

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. You look at your application, whatever it might be, and then think of the properties a molecule should have in order to fit.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's most important application is to act as an example of a comparatively stable chemical species containing bonding between two inert elements

Comment: It only exists in very special conditions, so that rather strongly limits its applications.

Comment: That's like asking for the practical use in sending a probe to Neptune or Pluto. There is none whatsoever. We still do it, because it has a lot of benefical economical and cultural side effects.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87830/were-goldii-complexes-synthesized-for-the-first-time-in-2017?r=SearchResults

Comment: I am currently writing an article (fun science stuff) about superacids. When it comes to carborane superacids, they are used to create that, so I wondered whether it's just a cool toy molecule, or if it is actually used for something.